# What happens if i write to DynamoDb data after a stale read?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, eventual-consistency

Let's say I'm using eventually consistent read mode. After my first write to a key with value *{"name":"Bob", "age":"1"}*, my read happens to return stale data from a replica (old value *{"name":"Bob", "age":"0"}*), and then i make a second write (based on this stale read) with value *{"name":"Cat", "age":"0"}*.

Then what happens in DynamoDb side?

1. it rejects my second write
2. it updates with the value {"name":"Cat", "age":"0"}
3. it updates with the value {"name":"Cat", "age":"1"}

If no.3 is correct behavior, then how it works behind the scenes? And how it knows that i didn't intentionally make the age as 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your answers it's no.2. By default, DynamoDB has eventually consistent reads, but writes are always strongly consistent.

The way it works:

- You always get 3 nodes, 1 for writes, 2 for reads
- On write, you send the request. Data is written to write node and synchronously replicated to one of read nodes. At this point you get a response.
- Data is asynchronously replicated between read nodes
- When you make a read, you have 50% chance of performing strongly consistent read (if you target, the node that had synchronous write)

Comment: So that means a normal write will always succeed no matter the previous read is stale or not. Do you have any reference link for this ?

Comment: I mostly get the knowledge from "The Dynamodb book". Pretty hard to find solid data online. But check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalUpdate I think it confirms my answer in relation to your question

Comment: that link describes the use case for multiple writes at same time. But it actually doesn't mention how to deal with a write which is based on a stale read for a single user (like the case in my question). i'm going to accept your answer, unless this idea is disproved later

Comment: I think that stale reads is not something you should worry on AWS. I haven't heard of such case. Also you can update entity partialy. So exclude field that shouldnt be updated from request